# I can't download any snap application even open the used once, Ubuntu LTS 22.04

Tags: command-line, snap

I can't download any snap application even open the used once. I am using Ubuntu LTS 22.04 the latest version.

```
 cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/code": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused
```

When try to check `systemctl` status :

```
 systemctl status snapd
× snapd.service - Snap Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-11-02 09:40:16 EAT; 5min ago
TriggeredBy: × snapd.socket
    Process: 10272 ExecStart=/usr/lib/snapd/snapd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 10272 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 447ms

Nov 02 09:40:16 rasjo-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cc5xx systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 02 09:40:16 rasjo-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cc5xx systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Nov 02 09:40:16 rasjo-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cc5xx systemd[1]: snapd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 02 09:40:16 rasjo-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cc5xx systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 02 09:40:16 rasjo-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cc5xx systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Nov 02 09:40:16 rasjo-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cc5xx systemd[1]: snapd.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
```

Answer (score 0):

***Warning: This solution removes the snap and all the packages installed via snap!***

You can try reinstalling `snapd`:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install snapd
```

After that you will have to reinstall all your snaps.

Comment: still facing the same error when i try to install any snap

Comment: Please edit your question and paste these there. It's very hard to read code from the comments. But from what I am seeing, you wrote `snap` instead of `snapd`.

Comment: @sotirov Why the hurry to "purge" :-) ... I would suggest first, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure snapd` and second, `sudo apt reinstall snapd` and see if either of those work before blowing it up with "purge" leaving this one as a last resort.