# How to solve "Error: cannot communicate with server" that I get whenever I try to access or isntall any snap?

Tags: boot, snap

I keep getting this error whenever I try to access or install any snap:

```
Error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/spotify": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Would you please show the output of `systemctl status snapd.socket` by [edit]ing your question and appending it there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't download any snap application even open the used once, Ubuntu LTS 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491205/i-cant-download-any-snap-application-even-open-the-used-once-ubuntu-lts-22-04)